# segmentation fault at rosrun rviz rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across a segmentation fault while trying rosrun rviz rviz. This issue has been discussed on this web( http://answers.ros.org/question/11376/rviz-segmentation-fault-at-launch/ ), but I think that essential issue has been not solved. The solution in the comment and the answer was to delete all of file in ~/.rviz. I also deleted all of files as I follow the instruction. But, the error doesn't go out.

```
[ INFO]rviz version 1.10.14
[ INFO]compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO]Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO]OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2)
Segmentation fault
```

I have checked the article (http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting). I can't find the way to solve the issue on the article. Could anyone give me clues? Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150801/segmentation-fault-at-rosrun-rviz-rviz/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The type of graphics card you use always is crucial when looking at rviz crashes (you can edit your answer to add that information). The rule of thumb is: "Nvdidia GPUs with propietary drivers generally work well, others might crash occasionally (or always in a absolute worst case)". With your GPU and driver known, I´d recommend googling something like "rviz crashes ros answers [your graphics card type]". There are tons of posts on rviz crashes on ROS Answers and it´s likely that there will be useful information in some of them.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher: Thank you for your advice! I will check it out tomorrow. Sorry, here is at midnight.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-08**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher: I was looking over the article on the web(http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Rviz%20in%20Stereo). Do you think that this contents connects with my issues?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-08**:
Unless you try something with stereo mode, no. I assume you installed from .deb packages?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-09**:
I don't make sense, I was googling to search for the cause and how to fix it. I also tried the method on the web
(https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/713), but segmentation fault didn't go out. I will reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I spent a load of time fixing these issues. What I realised is that Virtualbox is being a nasty little rascal with it's 3d Acceleration.

Switching if off fixed these issues for me.

Switch off your VM
Just go to the VM Settings -> Display -> Uncheck Enable 3D Acceleration.
Start your VM again.
Rejoice!

---

Originally posted by [sachitv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30047/sachitv/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iguanaistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30119/iguanaistic/) on 2017-04-21**:
Thank you! This worked for me.